# Using modulus to close divs, a new one opens when there's no content in it

Tags: php

So, it's hard to explain, but whenever I go to use a modulus to close my row after every 2 fields from ACF's repeater field, my code opens up another div and then either Chrome closes it, or I'm missing something. So, in my development, I have 4 entries. Now, this works by opening and closing `s_flex_start row` twice, but then it opens it a third time and I'm not sure what I am missing.

[Here is a link to the site with the issue in question. It's towards the bottom of the page, right below the 2nd slider.](http://arch.littlejackdev.com/services/)

Here is my code.

```
  <?php if( have_rows('s_repeater') ): ?>
    <?php //Call to $x ?>
    <?php $x = 1; ?>

    <div class="s_flex_start row">

      <?php while( have_rows('s_repeater') ): ?>

        <?php //Add one to $x ?>
        <?php $x++; ?>

            <div class="col-xs-6">
                Content here
            </div>

        <?php if ( $x % 2 != 0 && $x != 0 ) : ?>
            </div><div class="s_flex_start row">
        <?php endif; ?>

      <?php endwhile; ?>

  <?php endif; ?>
```

EDIT: As a solution to this issue, I went ahead and just used `flexbox` to adjust to columns.

Comment: Of course it does. When you close the div you always open another one

Comment: Yes, but I'm trying to close it on the 2nd entry, and then reopen it on the 3rd. Since $x doesn't go beyond 4, idk why it would open a 3rd row. Is there a better way for me to have coded this?

Comment: Exerytime you output this line `</div><div class="s_flex_start row">` you are closing a div and opening the next one. So on row 4 you close the second div and open a third. Code needs refactoring

Comment: Any suggestions

Comment: What does the result of `have_rows('s_repeater')` look like. Show us what data youare processing

Comment: https://codeshare.io/5Z087G

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/129541/discussion-between-ishio-and-riggsfolly).